# Integral over volume between two ellipsoids

Tags: multiple-integral, ellipsoids

Given [2 ellpsoids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GclkS.png), the outer with semi-major axes $A,B,C$ and the inner with semi-major axes $a,b,$ and $c$. I am supposed to integrate $\frac{1}{(\text{current volume})^3}$ (the volume at the current radius, not constant over the integral; (current volume) $=\frac{4\pi}{3}r^3$ for a sphere) over the volume between the ellipsoids. I tried mapping the ellipsoids to separate unit spheres, i.e.

$8 ABC \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_0^1\frac{1}{(\text{current volume})^3}r^2\sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$

using octant symmetry and the Jacobian $|J|=ABC$ for the outer ellipsoid.

I became stuck here due to a lack a formulation for the current volume and also due to convergence problems of $\frac{1}{r}$ evaluated at zero.
Is my approach sound? Is there a parameterization that allows the solution of this problem?

Comment: What is current volume? If it is a constant (which you would expect a volume to be) then pull it outside the integral.

Comment: The current volume is the volume at the current radius. In the case of the unit sphere, the current volume would be the radius cubed, which shouldn't be constant over the integral.

Comment: I think that requires to be included in the question. Also, for the unit sphere it is $\frac43 \pi r^3$ and $r$ would vary from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Good point, added.

Comment: I still struggle to see how "current volume" could be canonically defined. It is the volume of the ellipsoiod between the two ellipsoids as you integrate from inner to outer. But, if the inner and outer ellipsoids are distorted in different directions, then at "half" way inbetween, what ellipsoid's volume are you measuring? Imagine a really small egg sitting horizontally inside a really large egg that sits vertically. If you imagine an ellipsoid changing from the inner to the outer, it is constantly being distorted. To define "current volume" you require to define how this distortion happens

Comment: May I also add that you cannot independently map both ellipsoids to a sphere. You are mapping the region of integration. A mapping such that the outer ellipsoid is a sphere will not necessarily map the inner ellipsoid to a sphere. In the case that they are distorted in the same way, that is $\frac{A}{a} = \frac{B}{b} = \frac{C}{c}$ then mapping the outer to a sphere will map the inner to a sphere and also map current volume to $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ and the problem is simple. For the general case the problem is far more complex.

Comment: I see -- thank you for the insight. Could you elaborate on the case of the same distortion ($\frac{A}{a}= \frac{B}{b}= \frac{C}{c}$)?

Comment: Well in that case, as inner ellipsoid, current volume, and outer ellipsoid are all ellipsoids that are distorted in the same direction, a mapping that maps one to a sphere will map all to a sphere, and you will end up with what you have in the question with current volume equal to $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$. (except $r$ should vary from $R_0$ to $R_1$ not from $0$ to $1$). I would map the outer ellipsoid to the unit sphere and see what the inner ellipsoid is mapped to to determine $R_0$.

Comment: OK, that is much clearer now. I see this as the solution, if you put it in an answer I will mark as accepted.